# Uniformly bounding the difference of two logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

Consider two logarithmic functions defined as $g(\epsilon) = \log \epsilon $ and $ f(\epsilon) = \log (\epsilon + \epsilon^2 )$ for $0<\epsilon <1$. Can I find a $\delta > 0$ such that the difference $g(\epsilon) - f(\epsilon)$ is uniformly bounded on the interval $(0,\delta)$: $$ \sup_{\epsilon\in (0,\delta)} |g(\epsilon)-f(\epsilon)| = M < \infty ? $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obser that $|g(\epsilon) - f(\epsilon)| = \log(1+\epsilon) < \epsilon < 1 =\delta $ or use $\log(1+\epsilon) < \log 2 = M$. Either one works.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @mathwizard: My pleasure.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061023/ignoring-higher-order-terms-in-computations-involving-real-analytic-functions). It's a somewhat related question on power series and logarithms. Thanks!